# How to search for words only if they are at the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: google-search

Is there a way to specify the following in Google Search?

I want to search for a word only at the start of the sentences. So it should begin with a capital letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google case sensitive search;

http://case-sensitive-search.appspot.com/

> This application will Google query terms (the first input box), scan through the results in a specific range (From:From+Limit) and filter out those results where the filter terms (second input box; if empty, then same as the query terms) does not appear exactly in the same case as given by the user.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any [official search operators](http://www.google.com/intl/en/help/operators.html) or [undocumented search operators](http://www.googleguide.com/advanced_operators.html) to search for words only if they are in the beginning of a sentence.

You could try doing a exact [phrase search](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=136861) by putting double quotes around the set of words *to tell Google to consider the exact words in that exact order without any change.*